# linux hosted svn server but windows based automatic build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net, nant

We would like to move into the CI direction and face the following situation. We have a Linux based SVN server hosted by another team. We are a small .Net software team and would like to run automatic unit and integration tests over night and get feedback in the morning. Which (cheap) options do we have in this situation? Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where your SVN server is hosted.
SVN server provides you a platform-agnostic way to communicate with it.

So you are able to use either CI server you prefer.
If you want to get it for free, I'd recommend to use Team City (free version is limited in some ways but it will be definitely enough if your team is small).

You can host your Team City on any server you control and setup connection to SVN via URL.

Answer (score 1):

As for window based automatic build I recommend the following below:

1. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) - It has a lot of plugins. Easy to manage, install and configure.
2. [CruiseControl.net](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) - It is great as well and highly configurable. In my opinion it does have a big learning curve but it is worth the learning.
3. [RedGate Deployment Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/) - This one looks promising. I have not used it however I have always been a fan of RedGate products. RedGate always deliver fully polished products.